# Chrome Extension: Inject Button with modal JQuery Window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

i tried a lot of things but cant get it working.
I want an Chrome Extension which injects an button which opens a modal dialog with jquery/bootstrap.

I included the resources but it only works if the base site has the scripts and css already.

Can someone help? what is wrong?

```js
background.js:

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    // ...inject 'jquery.min.js' and...
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: "jquery.min.js",
        allFrames: true,
        runAt: "document_idle"
    });
    // ...inject 'content.js' into the active tab's page
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: "boostrap.bundle.min.js",
        allFrames: true,
        runAt: "document_idle"
    });
});
```

```css
manifest:
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "author": "Test",
  "permissions": [
    "storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs", "activeTab", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "action":{
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Test"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": [
      "modal.html",
      "modal.css",
      "config.json",
      "bootstrap.min.css",
      "bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map",
      "bootstrap.min.css.map"
    ],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["jquery.min.js","bootstrap.bundle.min.js", "content-script.js", "init.js"],
      "css" : ["modal.css", "bootstrap.min.css"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    },
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["jquery.min.js","bootstrap.bundle.min.js"],
      "css" : ["bootstrap.min.css"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "icons": { "16": "iconNeu.png",
    "48": "iconNeu.png",
    "128": "iconNeu.png" }
}
```

```html
content-script:

$(document).ready(function() {
    var path = chrome.runtime.getURL('modal.css');
    $('head').append($('<link>')
        .attr("rel","stylesheet")
        .attr("type","text/css")
        .attr("href", path));
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    var path = chrome.runtime.getURL('jquery.min.js');
    $('head').append($('<script>')
        .attr("src", path));
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    var path = chrome.runtime.getURL('bootstrap.min.css');
    $('head').append($('<link>')
        .attr("rel","stylesheet")
        .attr("type","text/css")
        .attr("href", path));
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    var path = chrome.runtime.getURL('bootstrap.bundle.min.js');
    $('head').append($('<script>')
        .attr("src", path));
});


fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('/modal.html'))
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
            addButton(data)
        }
    }).catch(err => {
    // handle error
        alert(err)
});


function addButton(data)
{
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.innerHTML = data
        document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

}
```

```html
The modal.html

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id = "btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

calling with $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
also not working. Only if i statically bet the scripts in the test site i can get it working.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

     Bootstrap CSS 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question seems to be about loading assets and not any of the things in your title. Please see [ask], then see if you revise to simplify and clarify the problem. There's a lot going on up there.

Comment: You have invalid (uncommented) text in your document head. Maybe that's a problem.